# AWS EKS Consul - Ingress ALB and downstream

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, consul, hashicorp

We are designing a new cluster for our application. We are required to use AWS EKS and Consul. We have the following questions:

**1) Is it possible to set an AWS ALB ingress (Application load balancing on Amazon EKS - Amazon EKS) as downstream from consul so I can manage it in the rules?**

In our local tests we used an nginx ingress and it worked perfectly, but in EKS, nginx ingress uses classic load balancers and these will be deprecated on August 15, 2022 (Elastic Load Balancing migrate-classic-load-balancer.html).
Obviously we can’t create a new project with something that is going to be deprecated so soon.

**2) Is ingress-gateway a replacement? Is it possible to create ingress-gateway using ALB ingress-controller from EKS? In the same case, ingress-gateway uses in AWS Classic load balancer and we have the same problem when deprecation.**

**3) Following this guide: Deploy Consul on Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) | Consul - HashiCorp Learn I see that no type of ingress controller is taken into account, so does it make sense to control external access to services from Consul? Or would income control suffice?**

Thank you very much!
Any advice or documentation will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: The classic load balancer thing doesn't have anything to do with nginx ingress. Your system provisions ELB classic because you haven't installed and configured the load balancer add-on: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html. The built-in one is limited on EKS.